# Access SQL: How to group by from a view (subquery in Access SQL)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which has the following columns:

-**Agent Name** -**Ticket ID** -**Requester's Email**

How can I get Agent name along with the number of customers who submit more than 1 tickets?

Example Result:

- Jennifer 2
- Mike 6

Means that Agent Jennifer takes care of 2 customers who submitted more than 1 tickets, Mike takes care of 6 such customers.
I am using MS Access....

What I can do is: 
`SELECT agent alias, Count(email) AS [CountOfvisitor email]
FROM table
GROUP BY agent alias, email
HAVING (((Countemail)>1));`

But this gives me something like:

- Jennifer 3
- Jennifer 6
- Jennifer 2

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

## Edit

```
select agentName,count(*) from (
  Select AgentName,email,count(*) from TableName 
  group by AgentName,email
  having count(*)>1
)t group by agentName
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding , I' edit the query using subquery.

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

`SELECT Agent, Count(Tickets) FROM [your table] WHERE Tickets > 1`

If you are looking for specific agent then:

`SELECT Agent, Count(Tickets) FROM [your table] WHERE Tickets > 1 AND agent = 'agent name'`